# Angular 2+ update template values using pipe

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular-template-variable

I am writing a checkout view of a shopping cart where an `array` is displayed with the items to be purchased like this:

**app.component.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let x of shoppingarray">
  <!-- Other code here... -->
</div>
```

I want to give the user the possibility of adding more items to the list at the last minute but somehow the total doesn't refresh even though I update the `array` and the subtotals.

I do update the subtotals on the `array` by incrementing a quantity var which affects directly the `objects` in the `array` like this:

**app.component.ts**

```js
AddmoreItemsOFThistype(a) {
  this.shoppingarray[a].qt+= 1;
}
```

Then I recalculate each subtotal by passing each subtotal through a `pipe` giving as parameter the `x.qt` which is the incremented quantity (the pipe just multiplies `x.price * x.qt`).

**app.component.html**

```html
<div> {{ x.price | totalPerItem: x.qt }} </div>
```

The problem is that the global `total` won't update values that have been returned from the `filters`.

**app.component.html**

```html
<div> {{ shoppingarray | CalculateTotalpipe }} </div>
```

`CalculateTotalpipe` just loops the whole `array` adding all `totals`, somehow the initial `total` is correct but modifications to the subtotals don't take effect.

**Is there any way to refresh `shoppingarray` so that `CalculateTotalpipe` generates an updated `total`?**

**Is there a better approach to this?**

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a variable total in your component? If you do have you bind that variable alone with [(ngModel)] in your view?

Comment: I do have one but I don't get how can I use it in combination with the filter in the view since I am extracting the global total straight from the filter that operates on the whole array `{{shoppingarray|CalculateTotalpipe}}` .  Any suggestion on how to combine the `[(ngModel)]` with the var total and the filter alltogether? . I

Comment: Read https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes. You shouldn't use a pipe. Use a regular method of your component, or precompute the total every time a quantity changes.

Comment: Problem solved: Using pure pipes was not the right approach. After declaring pipes as Impure it was solved. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I did include one unchangeable  "key": number  to my array containing the base price so that every time an item is added I update the array ` AddmoreItemsOFThistype(a){
this. shoppingarray[a].price += this. shoppingarray[a].qt * this. shoppingarray[a].baseprice;}`.   Then I declared the pipes as impure and that did the trick!!!!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Andres be cautious with the usage of impure pipes.
As it is written in the documentation:

> Angular executes an impure pipe during every component change
>   detection cycle. An impure pipe is called often, as often as every
>   keystroke or mouse-move.

This means, every time the user will move the mouse or scroll the page your total amount will be recalculated.
This will introduce performance issues.

I would advise to find another way of implementing the total without using a pipe. Why not use a simple service?